# Reusable Templates

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

Instead of creating text boxes everytime for the displaying the name of the blocks, I thought of creating a reusable template for the same. Following is what I created

```
partial block BlockTemplate
  annotation(Icon(coordinateSystem(extent = {{-100,-100},{100,100}}, preserveAspectRatio = true, initialScale = 0.1, grid = {2,2}), graphics = {Text(origin = {-0.366361,-0.51471}, lineColor = {0,0,255}, extent = {{-150,150},{150,110}}, textString = "%name"),Text(origin = {0,-260}, lineColor = {0,0,255}, extent = {{-150,150},{150,110}}, textString = "%name")}));
end BlockTemplate;
```

Then I imported this in another block by using

```
extends BlockTemplate
```

Turns out that I get the %name displayed on top of the block but I cannot edit it.

What should be done so that I am able to edit it?

Thanks in advance,
MSK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK then you can do it like this,

**Block A**

```
block A
  annotation (Icon(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false, extent={{-100,-100}, {100,100}}), graphics={Text(extent={{-52,50},{62,-20}}, lineColor={0,0,255}, textString="%name")}));
end A;
```

**Block B**

```
block B
  extends A;
end B;
```

**Block C**

```
block C
  B abc annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-60,20},{-40,40}})));
end C;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use Text annotation with extends like this. You need to create an instance of the block.

```
block A

  annotation (Icon(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false, extent={{-100,-100},
            {100,100}}), graphics={Text(
          extent={{-52,50},{62,-20}},
          lineColor={0,0,255},
          textString="%name")}));
end A;
```

Above is the block which defines a text annotation with %name.

```
block B

  A a annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-40,20},{-20,40}})));
end B;
```

Block B contains a component of Block A which will automatically display the name of the component in place of %name.

Comment: This does not serve the purpose, Adeel. Taking your answer as an example, what I want is block A to have a template which would help in naming B. So that when I Drag and Drop B onto another model C, I want A to display B's name in the diagram view of C.

Comment: Doing what you said will show the name of A in the Diagram View of B